# Using rsync to sync two directories on server and localhost, but size is different

Tags: debian, rsync, disk-usage

I'm using rsync to sync a directory from server to localhost:

```
rsync -avz --delete ./Stuff user@host:/Stuff
```

This all works fine, but how come when I type 'du -s' in both the server and the localhost I get different numbers?

Comment: have you tried to do a diff of both directories to see what the differences are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible reasons for the differing output from `du -s`:

- Different [file system block sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_%28data_storage%29), resulting in some files taking more space at one end or the other.
- Some of the files may be [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). You aren't using the `--sparse` option, so those would be filled in on the destination. If you were using that option it would be possible that some files which weren't actually sparse at the source became so at the destination.
- Some of the files may be hard-linked.  You aren't using the `--hard-links` option, so any hard linked files within the source will appear as multiple copies on the destination.

Using `du --apparent-size` may result in the same sizes being reported at both ends.

Comment: what do you mean by a "sparse" file? I'm not using symlinks or hardlinks, and I don't what what "block sizes" are.

Comment: I've added links to explanations of those concepts to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you issue a --delete there is a chance that you have extraneous files in there. rsync won't delete by default, so the directories won't be in sync

Comment: I tried again with --delete and there was nothing to delete, but sizes are still different.

Comment: The other thing you could try is adding a -vv and --inplace (which will update destination files in-place) Other than that, you might want to do an ls of both the source and target directories and diff them.

Comment: Thanks, but the above answer seems to be what the issue is -- different block sizes (not really sure what this means). Files are the same.